# Localization of custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm working on a project in which I'd like to move all strings used in the app to a single file, so they can be easily changed and updated. However I'm having trouble with the custom validation. I have validations in my app as follows:

```
validate :thing_is_correct

def thing_is_correct
  unless thing.is_correct
    errors[:base] << "Thing must be correct"
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to move "Thing must be correct" into my en.yml file and out of the model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails Way to do that would be to use [the mechanism described in the Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes).

`errors` is an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors`. New messages can be added by calling [`ActiveModel::Errors#add`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add). As you can see in the docs, you can not only pass a message but also a symbol representing the error:

```
def thing_is_correct
  unless thing.is_correct?
    errors.add(:thing, :thing_incorrect)
  end
end
```

Active Model will automatically try fetching the message from the namespaces described in the Guides (see the link above). The actual message is generated using [`ActiveModel::Errors#generate_message`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-generate_message).

To sum up:

1. Use `errors.add(:think, :thing_incorrect)`
2. Add `thing_incorrect` under one of [the YAML keys listed in the Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes).

Comment: This seems like a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the I18n inside the model.

```
validate :thing_is_correct

def thing_is_correct
  unless thing.is_correct
    errors[:base] << I18n.t('mymodel.mymessage')
  end
end
```

Inside `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  mymodel:
    mymessage: "Thing must be correct"
```

Inside another locale: (`config/locales/es.yml`)

```
es:
  mymodel:
    mymessage: "Esto debe ser correcto"
```

If you set `I18n.locale = :en`, the message inside `en.yml` will be displayed. If you set it to `:es`, the one inside `es.yml` will be used instead.

Comment: Active Model has a mechanism for that and it stores the errors under different keys. If you use this then your custom errors will be stored somewhere else which will create a mess.